# Copy value in previous row if not set

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to write a `SELECT` query for BigQuery that sets the value of a column to the value in the previous row, if in the current row it is set to NULL.

I have something like this for now:

`SELECT *, IFNULL(tag, LAG(tag) OVER(ORDER BY id)) as new_tag FROM tags`

...but it only copies values into adjacent NULL rows. Is there some way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

[LAG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag) window function doesn't support `IGNORE NULLS` clause, so use [LAST_VALUE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#last_value) function along with `IGNORE NULLS` instead. If applied to your query,

```sql
SELECT *, LAST_VALUE(tag IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY id) as new_tag FROM tags
```